# How to set variables and properties that could be made configurable using the Project Properties' UI in Visual Studio, for a wix setup project?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, wix, target, heat

I am working on WiX Setup V3 project in Visual Studio 2019. I have to make this working in Visual Studio as well as from MSBuild (in Jenkins). I have authored custom target file which will be included in this project. Following is the markup of the custom target file. I cannot use the HeatDirectory task, since it lacks some flags like svb6. Hence I am using Exec command for Heat execution.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>  
    <DefineConstants>HeatFldrPath=$(FilePath);ProductVersion=$(PVersion);BuildNumber=$(BldNum)</DefineConstants>    
    <OutputName>$(MSIName)</OutputName>
    <OutputPath>$(MSIPath)</OutputPath>
    <SuppressPdbOutput>True</SuppressPdbOutput> 
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WixBinPath>$(SolutionDir)\Build\wix\</WixBinPath>
    <WixToolPath>$(WixBinPath)\</WixToolPath>
    <WixTargetsPath>$(WixToolPath)Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
    <WixTasksPath>$(WixToolPath)wixtasks.dll</WixTasksPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <WixExtension Include="WixUtilExtension">
      <HintPath>lib\WixUtilExtension.dll</HintPath>
      <Name>WixUtilExtension</Name>
    </WixExtension>
    <WixExtension Include="WixUIExtension">
      <HintPath>lib\WixUIExtension.dll</HintPath>
      <Name>WixUIExtension</Name>
    </WixExtension>
    <WixExtension Include="WixMsmqExtension">
      <HintPath>lib\WixMsmqExtension.dll</HintPath>
      <Name>WixMsmqExtension</Name>
    </WixExtension>
    <WixExtension Include="WixIIsExtension">
      <HintPath>lib\WixIIsExtension.dll</HintPath>
      <Name>WixIIsExtension</Name>
    </WixExtension>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="HeatTarget" BeforeTargets="Build">   
    <Exec  Command='"$(WixToolPath)\heat.exe" dir $(HeatFldrPath) -cg UserFeatureFiles -dr APP_DIR -gg -g1 -sfrag -sw -svb6 -srd -sreg -ke -var var.HeatFldrPath -out "Content\UserFiles.wxs"' />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

I need to make this configurable for the following parameters:

- Product Version (for use in Candle command)
- Build Number (This will be added to the Product Version)
- Heat Directory Path
- MSI Name (This will have Version along with Build Number concatenated
  to it)
- MSI Path (I don't want this to be bin\$(Configuration)\en-us, rather
  a custom directory I specify)

My custom targets file will be imported to the .wixproj file and nothing else will be changed in the .wixproj file.

If I use DefineConstants in my custom targets file, it works with MSBuild, but not with Visual Studio. I am having a hard time passing these as parameters and getting my MSI to build from both Visual Studio and MSBuild. I tried passing $(FilePath), $(PVersion) and $(BldNum) from project properties, but no luck. I cannot hard code these values in .targets or .wixproj file, since they have to be run from both Visual Studio and MSBuild. Also, I am not able to pass OutputName and OutputPath from Visual Studio. Can anyone please help me?

PFB the wixproj file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" 
    InitialTargets="EnsureWixToolsetInstalled" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
      <PropertyGroup>
       <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' 
     ">Debug</Configuration>
        <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
       <ProductVersion>3.10</ProductVersion>
       <ProjectGuid>{9ecbe76b-ecc4-4a17-bc8b-f2224421f616}</ProjectGuid>
       <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
       <OutputName>My.Custom.MSI</OutputName>
       <OutputType>Package</OutputType>
       <PublishDir>..\HeatFolder</PublishDir>
       </PropertyGroup>
       <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 
       'Debug|x86' ">
       <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
       <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
       <DefineConstants>Debug;HeatFldrPath=$(PublishDir)</DefineConstants>
       </PropertyGroup>
       <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 
       'Release|x86' ">
       <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
       <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>


       <WixVariables>$(FilePath)=$(ProjectDir)HeatFolder;$(PVersion)="1.1.0.1" 
       </WixVariables>


  <DefineConstants>HeatFldrPath=$(FilePath);ProductVersion=1.1.0.1;BuildNumber=$ 
        (BldNum)</DefineConstants>
        </PropertyGroup>
        <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Full- 
        Release|x86' ">
        <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
        <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
        <DefineConstants>Release;HeatFldrPath=$(PublishDir)</DefineConstants>
        </PropertyGroup>
        <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="Content\GlobalCustomActions.wxs" />
        <Compile Include="Content\GlobalExitDlg.wxs" />
        <Compile Include="Content\GlobalFatalError.wxs" />
        <Compile Include="Content\GlobalInstallDlg.wxs" />
        <Compile Include="Content\GlobalLicenseAgreementDlg.wxs" />
        <Compile Include="Content\GlobalSetupFolderDlg.wxs" />
        <Compile Include="Content\GlobalWelcomeDlg.wxs" />
        <Compile Include="Content\GlobalWixUI.wxs" />
        <Compile Include="Content\Product.wxs" />
        <Compile Include="Content\UserFiles.wxs" />
        <Compile Include="Content\UserIIS.wxs" />
        <Compile Include="Content\UserRegistry.wxs" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="conf\" />
        <Folder Include="Content\" />
        <Folder Include="Images\" />
        <Folder Include="lib\" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="AppPoolAttrs.xml" />
        <Content Include="AppPoolUpgradeChanges.xml" />
        <Content Include="conf\default.yml" />
        <Content Include="Content\CustomActions.CA.dll" />
        <Content Include="Content\GlobalProperties.wxi" />
        <Content Include="Content\License.en-us.rtf" />
        <Content Include="CustomWix.targets" />
        <Content Include="Images\Banner.bmp" />
        <Content Include="Images\DEST.ICO" />
        <Content Include="Images\dialog.bmp" />
        <Content Include="Images\dialog_cust.bmp" />
        <Content Include="Images\dialog_template.bmp" />
        <Content Include="Images\Exclam.ico" />
        <Content Include="Images\folder.ico" />
        <Content Include="Images\folderNew.ico" />
        <Content Include="Images\New.ico" />
        <Content Include="Images\warn.ico" />
        <Content Include="lib\WixIIsExtension.dll" />
        <Content Include="lib\WixMsmqExtension.dll" />
        <Content Include="lib\WixUIExtension.dll" />
        <Content Include="lib\WixUtilExtension.dll" />
        <Content Include="packages.config" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <ItemGroup>
        <EmbeddedResource Include="Content\en-us.wxl" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <Import Project="CustomWiX.Targets" 
           Condition="Exists('CustomWiX.targets')" />
           <Import Project="$(WixTargetsPath)" Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' 
            != '' " />
            <Import 
           Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets" 
           Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' AND 
           Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets') 
           " />
           <Target Name="EnsureWixToolsetInstalled" Condition=" 
           '$(WixTargetsImported)' != 'true' ">
           <Error Text="The WiX Toolset v3.11 (or newer) build tools must be 
           installed to build this project. To download the WiX Toolset, see 
            http://wixtoolset.org/releases/" />
            </Target> 
            </Project>
```

Comment: Can you share your `wixproj` file? `OutputName` can be configured through project properties, `OutputPath` is related to project location (but you can copy the result MSI to any location). Also, how does `DefineConstants` look like?

Comment: Hi Pavel, Thanks a lot for your reply. The wixproj file has been added to the original question. Please refer it and help.

Comment: Hi Pavel, Thanks for the reply. In the OutputName, I wanted to have the build number and version number too, and I do not want to hardcode these. Is there a mechanism to achieve the same?

Comment: Hi @PerryQian-MSFT, the resolution you gave is promising, but I do not want to provide the value using any property under the .targets file, instead I wanted to provide it using the project-properties UI under Visual Studio. A solution for the same would do my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried passing $(FilePath), $(PVersion) and $(BldNum) from project
>   properties, but no luck. I cannot hard code these values in .targets
>   or .wixproj file, since they have to be run from both Visual Studio
>   and MSBuild. Also, I am not able to pass OutputName and OutputPath
>   from Visual Studio.

The main issue is that when you set the variables in `Project Properties UI`, the values can only pass to the variables in the `xxx.wixproj` rather than `CustomWiX.Targets` file. 
And this approach is local (modify only the properties of the xxx.wixproj file, which still be overridden by the custom target values).

In more detail, when it reloads the `xxxx.wixproj` which contains the custom target file, MSBuild will load the xml nodes line by line, since MSBuild properties support forward override values. Simply said, if the same value is defined later, the previous value is overwritten. And the same properties are defined in the custom target file which is imported under the those properties, so the properties in the custom targets file will always override the properties.

**Besides**, when you pass some variables in the `project Properties UI`, the values will overwrite the values in the `xxx.wixproj`rather than custom targets file. And then when you build again, the values in custom targets will still override the values you modified in project properties, so it won't work.

Differ from VS IDE, the msbuild command line can override the value with `-p: XXX (property name)= XXXXXX`, which is global, so this problem does not occur.

**Suggestion**

**1)** If you still want to modify those properties by overriding the value of the project properties, remove the same properties from the custom targets file and move them to wixproj so that they can be used directly.

**2)** Since the custom target file always overwrites the same properties, you can modify the specific properties directly in the custom target file without having to modify the wixproj file directly.

**Update1**

The wixvariables(`Properties-->Build-->Define Variables`) does not work in the `xxxx.wixproj` file but only for wix file like `Product.wxs`file. If you define the property $(Filepath) in the Define Variables, it will never be used for MSBuild. So there is no way to set the properties in `Property UI` for msbuild Properties.

Besides, `$` is used to call a property of MSBuild and MSBuild define a property only under PropertyGroup of xxx.xxxproj like `<PropertyGroup><FilePath> xxx</FilePath><\PropertyGroup>`.

**Solution**

You can customize your build by using [Directory.Build.targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59530057/how-to-set-variables-and-properties-that-could-be-made-configurable-using-the-pr) and remember keeping the name as the document said which is designed by that with the effect. Then you should put this file under the solution folder so that it can work for all the projects.`xxx.props` file will import on the top of the `xxxx.xxproj`, so it can not override the values and only the `Directory.Build.targets` which is imported at the bottom of the `xx.xxproj` file does.

Then you can define the variables in the file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup>
<FilePath>xxxxx</FilePath>
</ProperGroup>

.........
</Project>
```

Hope it could help you.

Comment: What if I do not want to change the .wixproj file or the custom .targets file? I want to configure the $(FilePath) using the project properties UI only and then utilize the same. How to do that?

Comment: If you define the `$(FilePath)` into <WixVariables> and then change the values in the `Properties-->Build-->Define Variables`, l am afraid it does not work. The `WixVariables` works for wix project like `Product.wxs` file not `xxxx.wixcsproj`. And the WixVariables are not properties. When you use $() to call FilePath, it meas it is a property of MSBuild which defines in this format(`<FilePath> xxx</FilePath>` in `propertygroup` of MSBuild).

Comment: After l do a long research, the properties UI for wix projects cannot pass the values into wixproj file. You can try to use [Directory.Build.targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019) under the the solution path.It can be applied to the whole solution of the project. You just need to create a new file called it, not modifying the initial targets file and `xxx.wixproj` files. You can set the the properties in it and every time you can change the properties in the Directory.Build.targets to override the values directly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Perry. Currently I am doing the same thing, by creating CustomWix.targets file and assigning value to FilePath using that. I was thinking to make it configurable using the UI, hence asked the question.